# SSIS - Script Component - Change icon based on results

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, ssis, etl

In my SSIS Script Component Task (NOT the Script task, which can be added to a Control Flow, but the Script Component Task, which is added within Data Flows), I added some error handling in the catch part of a `try, catch` block:

```
// No connection was created. Exit gracefully
bool cancelOnError = false;
ComponentMetaData.FireError(ErrorCode: 10, SubComponent: "SubComponent", 
Description: "Couldn't set up the connection. This could be because an invalid host was 
provided, or due to a firewall blocking the connection.", HelpFile: "", HelpContext: 0, 
pbCancel: out cancelOnError);
```

This all works fine, with the script task catching the error I raise in my code. I can also see the error in the logs:

```
Error: 0xA at DFT Extract, SubComponent: Couldn't set up the connection. 
This could be because an invalid host was provided, or due to a firewall 
blocking the connection.
```

However, the icon on on the task is green, and a subsequent task I defined to process results gets fired (there is nothing to process, though, as this particular error occurs prior to processing any data):

[image: Green icons]

The Data Flow correctly shows a red cross icon. Is there any way I can change the icon on the Script Component, or a better way for me to (elegantly) simulate a showstopping error?

I found [this page on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/comparing-the-script-task-and-the-script-component), showing the difference between Script Task and Script Components, which also states:

> The Script component runs as a part of the Data Flow task and does not
>   report results using either of these properties.

That doesn't have me very hopeful, but I am hoping someone might have a work around. I primarily think that showing the green icon is somewhat misleading when we trap an error.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just changing the cancelonerror value to true

```
bool cancelOnError = true;
```

Or you can use `Throw exception` method

```
throw new Exception("Couldn't set up the connection. This could be because an invalid host was 
provided, or due to a firewall blocking the connection.");
```

**Workaround**

If your goal is to ignore rows that was not processed correctly, the best way is to add a Column to the `OutputBuffer` (of type DT_BOOL), and set this column value to `False` if there is an error , else it's value must be `True`.

And add a conditional split after the script component to filter rows based on this Column. With a similar expression:

```
[FlagColumn] == True
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried setting to `True` before, but didn't really notice any difference. I'm mostly afraid that'd mean anything I processed correctly might not be sent to the output (we grab messages from a queue, and once they're off the queue, we won't see them again, so ensuring they go through correctly is crucial for us). I can give the Exception a go some time soon, though. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @SchmitzIT i added a workaround, it might helps you, check my answer update